# How do I make the carousel display all images with the same size so my footer doesn't get pushed down?

Tags: bootstrap-4

My carousel has 3 images and two are the same size with one about double the size.  When the large image loads it pushes my footer down which is beneath it.  How do I make all images appear the same size or can I adjust the height of the carousel?

Comment: Hi,

Can you please share us the sample?
Use jsfiddle or codepen to create and share the link.

Comment: Please post the relevant code as text in the question.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- Ideally, all images should be cropped to the same size
- In your case, we can add a condition of max-height with an arbitrary number (i added `500px` because that was the minimum height amongst the images I chose) to our images
- This led to empty spaces around the "taller" image... To highlight this point, I added a `lightpink` background to the carousel... and centered the image since it will be left aligned by default

**working snippet** below:

```css
.carousel-item {
  background-color: lightpink
}

.carousel-inner img {
  max-height: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel">

    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/Jumbo.jpg">
      </div>

    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev left" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next right" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```